# Help with diagram

Tags: graphics, diagrams, xy-pic

I do not have very much experience with the xy-pic package and I always try to figure out things by copying and pasting codes.

I am stuck in here: I would like to get an arrow from A to C with an upper name.

```
\xymatrix{ A \ar[r] ^a="a"  & B \ar[r] ^b="b" & C }
```

What I succeeded to plot is:

```
\xymatrix{A \ar[r] ^a="a" & B \ar[r] ^b="b" & C \ar @/^/ "a";"b" }
```

but I'd like the arrow to go from `A` to `C` :(

I appreciate any kind of help! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 8):

Just to offer an alternative, the [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package can also be used to produce commutative diagrams using the versatility of [`PGF/TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf); here's the code producing the desired diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 A \ar{r}{a}\ar[bend left=40]{rr}{b\circ a} & B \ar{r}{b} & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can add modifiers to the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
 A \ar[r]^a \ar@<3pt>@/^1pc/[rr]^{b\circ a} & B \ar[r]^b & C
}
\end{document}
```

With `@/^1pc/` you state that the arrow is curved, with `@<3pt>` you shift it a bit up, so the arrow tips near to *C* don't overlap.

[image]